# How can I return all rows from bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large `SQL INSERT` that I need to do.

The table is called `testResult` and has an `id`, `name` and `value` column.

The insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO testResult ( name, value )
VALUES
('Helium', '.001'),
('Oxygen', '.19'),
('Palladium', '.054'),
('Carbon', '.21'),
...etc
```

The `id` is an identity type column and is auto generated by Sql Server.

Is there a way to return the inserted values along with the auto-generated Id after I do the insert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `OUTPUT` clause does exactly that.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO testResult (name, value)  
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
VALUES
('Helium', '.001'),
('Oxygen', '.19'),
('Palladium', '.054'),
('Carbon', '.21');
```

You can specify exact column names, like `INSERTED.id`.

This is all done within one SQL statement from your end, without the need to write separate `SELECT`.

[Check more in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Oh I see, so if I add the `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` to the large `INSERT` query, it will automatically return everything I just inserted including the auto-generated Ids?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell exactly :-)